# What type of Flare is best used in GA Survival kit?

Tags: general-aviation, emergency

I have a question regarding Survival Kit Signaling equipment for a General Aviation aircraft. what type of emergency Flares are recommended for aviation use? The Signaling gun with cartridges type or another type? I would appreciate if anyone could point me in the direction of some good Emergency flares for aviation Survival Kits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on your operations (day/night/land/water) but [this AC has some really good info](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC%2091-58A.pdf) on various types to cary in different situations. Although its important to note that flares are dangerous and flammable making them potentially hazardous in an aviation situation:

> The Federal Aviation Administration (FAA)  recognizes that many pilots
> and operators of aircraft are  utilizing some distress signaling
> devices that are inherently  dangerous, as well as ineffective, when
> used in actual  emergencies. Typical of the problem is the use of
> "railroad or  highway flares," which produce an excessive amount of
> high  temperature slag, usually burn the user when hand held, and are
> easily extinguished when used in open bodies of water. Further,  the
> incendiary nature of these and other pyrotechnics presents  problems
> for their safe and proper storage in the aircraft  environment. This
> advisory circular is written to guide the  pilot/operator in the
> proper use and identification of  pyrotechnic signaling devices.

This [survival kit](http://www.fl220.com/product/faa-survival-kit.html) includes both hand held and launching flares and seems to be marketed for aviation.